# wrote this program, but error is "The method setDefaultCloseOperation(int) is undefined for the type ButtonFrame" ,how can i solve?

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ButtonFrameTest{ 
    public static void main(String args[]){


        ButtonFrame button = new ButtonFrame();
        button.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        button.setSize(300, 200);


        button.setVisible(true);


    }//end main

}
```

Comment: What is a `ButtonFrame`?

Comment: It sounds like ButtonFrame isn't a valid frame....but I'd be guessing as you've not provided that class

Comment: is ButtonFreame a jframe?

Comment: Please put questions in your post, not the title of the post...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to say JFrame instead of ButtonFrame. Or maybe you want to make the class ButtonFrame to extend JFrame.